# How to install and import angular 2 '@angular/router'?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to use @angular/router from this [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). I tried to install this module using npm: `npm install @angular/router --save`
And I tried to import this module:

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
```

I get an error "Cannot find module '@angular/router'"
I looked at node_modules/@angular/router directory. It has 2 directories: angular1 and angular2. Should I import this module using:

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router/angular2/router.js';
```

Or this is incorrect module? It has only 3 files in angular2 directory: router.js, router.dev.js, router.min.js

Comment: Could you just verify which version of the router it was trying to pull? Look in the  package.json file for which version of the router it is pulling, most recent one should be 3.0.0-alpha.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html

You need to add it to your configuration

```
var routerVer = '@3.0.0-alpha.8'; // lock router version

var  map = {
  'app':                        'app',

  ...
  '@angular/router':            'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/router' + routerVer,
  ...
};
```